# Como faço para casar este intervalo de elementos?

Tags: regex

Como faço para pegar um texto entre esses dois elementos, por exemplo:

```
a) texto <br /> texto texto texto <br />
```

Gostaria de pegar o que há entre `a)` e o `<br />` do fim, só o do fim:

```
"texto <br /> texto texto texto"
```

https://regexr.com/3hdei

Comment: Qual seria o resultado após descartar?

Comment: texto <br /> texto texto texto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez não seja a melhor resposta, mas funciona como você deseja. Usei este Regex abaixo:

```
a\)\s.*(?=\s<)
```

Irá retornar:

```
a) texto <br /> texto texto texto
```

Em seguida faço um `replace` no `a)`, ficando apenas:

```
texto <br /> texto texto texto
```

```js
resultado = $('#texto1')
            .text()
            .match(/a\)\s.*(?=\s<)/)
            .toString()
            .replace('a) ','');

$('#texto2').text(resultado);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Texto original:
<br />
<textarea id="texto1" style="display: inline-block; width: 350px; height: 50px;">
Texto texto texto texto
a) texto <br /> texto texto texto <br />
b) texto <br /> texto texto texto <br />
</textarea>
<br />
Texto capturado:
<br />
<textarea id="texto2" style="display: inline-block; width: 350px; height: 20px; background: yellow;">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Funciona? Não acusa erro? Qual navegador você está usando? Chrome 61 acusa [esse erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Ior.png)

Comment: Eu não fazia ideia. Foi anunciado [aqui](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/07/upcoming-regexp-features#lookbehind_assertions) e implementado ([issue 4545](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4545&desc=2#c20)) no 21 de agosto no Chrome 62.

Comment: Opera 49+ ([status](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5668726032564224))

Comment: @ÐvÐ funcionou, era isso mesmo. Só que modifiquei assim a\).*(?=<br \/>) . Agora como faço na pergunta? Queria uma forma individual. https://regexr.com/3he44 . A pergunta será o texto inicial que sempre terminará com dois <br /><br /> porém no meio pode ter tags de formatação e outros <br />.

Comment: @ÐvÐ cara, agradeço, tô desistindo, ceheguei tão perto, mas... seu código funciona corretamente na vriavel texto, quando coloco ela em um textarea não funciona dá erro. To usando para pegar a pergunta: Set regx = New RegExp
regx.IgnoreCase = True
regx.Global = True
regx.Pattern = "(.|\n)*?(a\).*?)"
Set ParteString = regx.Execute(questao)
For Each Parte in ParteString
 pergunta=replace(Parte.Value,"a)","")
Next
Set regx = Nothing

Comment: @ÐvÐ questao=Request.Form("questao") é um editor textarea fckeditor, o estranho é que nas respostas funcionam. O seu código dá erro no RetStr = Matches(0) quando recupero com fckeditor.

Comment: @ÐvÐ eu pego o valor inteiro do textarea e individualemnte caso as regras, uma para pergunta e as outras para as respostas, depois jogo cada uma em uma variável onde pretendo gravar no banco.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69623/discussion-between-dvd-and-rod).

Answer (score 2):

É muito mais fácil remover o que você não quer:

- `^a\)\s*` no início, ou
- `\s*<br\s*/?>\s*$` no final.

Então:

```
^a\)\s*|\s*<br\s*/?>\s*$
```

usando a função `replace()` com as flags *`global`* e *`ignorecase`*.

Ou, se houver vários `<br>` no final:

```
^a\)\s*|\s*(?:<br\s*/?>\s*)+$
```

---

Sendo que está usando ASP classic:

```vb
Dim texto : texto = "a) texto <br /> texto texto texto <br />"

'RegEx
Set re = New RegExp
re.Global = true
re.IgnoreCase = true
re.Pattern = "^a\)\s*|\s*(?:<br\s*/?>\s*)+$"

texto = re.Replace(texto, "")

Set re = Nothing

Response.Write(texto)
```

Comment: não sei se foi vc que me forneceu essa expressão https://regexr.com/3qbc3 a tempos atras, foi?

Answer (score 2):

Já que ninguém ainda publicou uma resposta de como fazer isto em JavaScript **puro**, vou estar deixando minha resposta aqui também caso alguém precise.

```js
var txt = "a) texto <br /> texto texto texto <br />";
/a\)(.*)<br\s?\/>/.exec(txt)[1].trim(); // texto <br /> texto texto texto
```

Ou

```js
var txt = "a) texto <br /> texto texto texto <br />";
var rgx = /a\)(.*)<br\s?\/>/;
var res = rgx.exec(txt)[1].trim(); // texto <br /> texto texto texto
```

### Explicação

---

#### Regex

```js
/a\)(.*)<br\s?\/>/
```

- `a\)` - Procura por `a)`
- `(.*)` - Faz um grupo de captura com todos os termos encontrados (`.*`) exceto pelo `\n`, que pode ser capturado com `[^]` se necessário (Ou `[\S\s]`, caso não esteje trabalhando com JavaScript).
- `<br\s?\/>` - Procura por `<br/>` ou `<br />`

---

#### Javascript

Ao utilizar `/(.*)/` como expressão regular, o compilador criará um grupo de captura, que será o lugar onde texto será guardado. Sendo assim, podemos colocar textos antes e depois para limitar a captura.
Para retornar o texto de uma expressão, utilize:

```js
/exemplo/.exec(texto)[0]
```

No lugar do `0`, você pode trocar pelo grupo de captura criado. No seu regex, por exemplo, utiliza-se o número `1` para referenciar o grupo.

Já o método `String#trim()` foi utilizado para remover os espaços do começo e do fim. (opcional)

Comment: Boa resposta +1. Um detalhe: recomendaria usar `[\s\S]` em vez de `[^]` para evitar problemas de compatibilidade

Comment: Verdade né... O `[^]` é mais compacto, e também demora menos para compilar, mas esqueci desse detalhe. Boa, vou adicionar aqui!